# Gradle DSL method not found: 'setApplicationId()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle unable to find method setApplicationId(), I am using below configuration in build.gradle file :

```
 android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def mergedFlavor = variant.outputs

    switch (variant.flavorName) {

        case "appnameDev":

    mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.wexer.flavor.devtest")
            break
   }  
}


defaultConfig {
    // These are applied to the manifest, to prevent nasty compat modes, use the latest you can.
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following alternative worked for me :

```
  flavorDimensions 'white_label', 'server'
    productFlavors {
      labelOne{
         dimension "white_label"
         applicationId 'com.app.labelOne'

     }

    labelTwo{
        dimension "white_label"
        applicationId 'com.newapp.labelTwo'
    }


//build environments

    dev {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".devtest"
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"

    }
    integration {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".integration"
        versionNameSuffix "-integration"

    }
    staging {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        versionNameSuffix "-staging"

    }
    live {
        dimension "server"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
def mergedFlavor = variant.outputs
```

**Do**

```
def mergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor
```

Your code will be

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
    def mergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor 
    switch (variant.flavorName) { 
       case "appnameDev": 
       mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.wexer.flavor.devtest") 
       break
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run.`**

Comment: getting follow up error using above code:

versionName cannot be set on a mergedFlavor directly.
versionNameOverride can instead be set for variant outputs using the following syntax:
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionNameOverride = "1.0.0.74-1.0.0"
        }
    }

Comment: tried with changed var 'mergedFlavor' , same error.